# How to re-use this API Client that is based on the Ultimate RestSharp Client in ASP.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am a new C# developer and I am trying to re-use the API client that I built based on the ***Ultimate RestSharp Client in ASP.NET and C#*** explained [in this post](https://exceptionnotfound.net/building-the-ultimate-restsharp-client-in-asp-net-and-csharp/). I was able to create all the classes and prerequisites mentioned in the article, but I am unable to use the client class right now over some places in my application

Here's the client code:

```
public class UsersClient : BaseClient
{
    public UsersClient (ICacheService cache, IDeserializer serializer, IErrorLogger errorLogger)
        : base(cache, serializer, errorLogger, "http://yourBaseUrl.com") { }

    public User GetByID(int id)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("users/{id}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", id.ToString());
        return GetFromCache<User>(request, "User" + id.ToString());
    }

}
```

Now, when I am trying to call the GetById method in the code-behind of some ASP.NET pages, I could not see or access this method and I don't know why. Here's the line of code I am using to access the method:

```
string userId = "JohnA";
var user = UsersClient.GetById(userId);
```

So how can I access this method? or how can I use the API client over my application?

**UPDATE:**

I am still struggling with this API client. Could you please show me how I can use it and how I can apply dependency injection?

Comment: Why are you trying to access GetById() method as if it were static? You have to create a UsersClient object

Comment: @AnthonyLiriano, as mentioned in my question I am trying to access this method as I would like to use it in different places in my application. What is the best practice to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access non-static method like that. First you have to initialize UsersClient object.

```
ICacheService cache = //initialize cache here
IDeserializer deserializer = //initialize deserializer here
IErrorLogger errorLogger = //initialize errorLogger here
UsersClient usersClient = new UsersClient(cache, deserializer, errorLogger); 

string userId = "JohnA"; 
var user = usersClient.GetById(userId);
```

I would recommend to learn about design patterns like dependency injection and inversion of control (already used, not sure if it was intended or unconsciously)  and use them in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help in this regard. Could you please explain to me a little bit the best way of accessing this method? And how to use dependency injection and inversion of control?

Comment: @JohnNate Generally the solution that I provide to you is proper and you should use it. Anyway in really simplified way you can call methods in 2 different ways, depends if you method is static or not.

For example:
If method is static you can call it like you did in your question
    var user = UsersClient.GetById(userId);
If method is non-static (no 'static' keyword in method definition) you have to initialize class object from you want to call this method
    UsersClient usersClient = new UsersClient(...); 
    var user = usersClient.GetById(userId);

Comment: @JohnNate About dependency injection and inversion of control you will find lots of tutorials in the internet.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I am still confused about how to initialize an instance of `ICacheService`, `IDeserializer`...etc. I am getting errors when I defined them as `ICacheService cache = new ICacheService();`. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to access this method by static reference. You'll have to make the adjustments below. (Add the word static to the GetByID method).

```
public class UsersClient : BaseClient
{
    public UsersClient (ICacheService cache, IDeserializer serializer, IErrorLogger errorLogger)
        : base(cache, serializer, errorLogger, "http://yourBaseUrl.com") { }

    public static User GetByID(int id)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("users/{id}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", id.ToString());
        return GetFromCache<User>(request, "User" + id.ToString());
    }

}
```